# JSoup exclude table row

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am using JSoup selector to take rows from the table. But there is a problem, since on the website td class names are messed up, and hence I need to clean up my values and exclude those elements from the list. How would I select to remove the whole row from table, if say my activity Element contains word 'dancing'?

```
    String url = "https://golf.procon.org/met-values-for-800-activities/";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Element table = doc.select("table").get(1);

    Iterator<Element> activity = table.select("td[class=xl75]").iterator();
    Iterator<Element> specification = table.select("td[class=xl72]").iterator();
    Iterator<Element> metAmount = table.select("td[class=xl73], td[class=xl74]").iterator();
```

Elements look like this:

```
<td class="xl73" style="border-width: medium 0.5pt 0.5pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: windowtext; width: 91pt; height: 11.25pt; background-color: transparent;" width="121" height="15">dancing</td>
```

And I need to exclude elements like this, and possibly all the columns after this one till the end of row.
Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude elements with given text, you should use the `not` and `contains` [pseudo selectors:](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

```
table.select("td[class=xl75]:not(:contains(dancing))")
```